# CPU Usage Date Predicate SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I'm retrieving some data using a date field predicate(non clustered) and I'm trying to use 2 alternatives to achieve my goals.
The field is a `datetime` and in one of the statements I'm using literally the value stored in the field

```
WHERE dataload ='2012-07-16 10:13:01.307'
```

In the other statement I'm using this predicate.

```
WHERE dataload >= DATEADD(DAY,0,datediff(day,0,@Dataload)) 
  and dataload <= dateadd(ms,-3,DATEADD(DAY,1,datediff(day,0,@Dataload)))
```

Looking at the statistics IO/time output, the reads are the same, but the method #1 used 16ms of CPU and the method #2 used 0ms causing the method #1 to consume 61% of the total cost over the 39%of the method #2.

I'm not understanding really why the CPU are being used in #method1 when the method #2 has so many functions on it and gives me 0ms.

There is any basic explanation for it ?

Answer (score 0):

The first method retrieves the field from disk, taking `6 msec.  The second method just fetches the data from memory.  If you reversed the order, the other method would take longer.